# Firebase - Handling max concurrent connection errors (free plan)

Tags: javascript, firebase

Firebase's [pricing page FAQ](https://www.firebase.com/pricing.html#faq-section) states the following:

> The free plan has a hard cap at 50 concurrent connections. When the
>   51st user tries to connect, the API will throw an error and any
>   additional connections will fail.

Is there any way to gracefully handle this error (both for the 51st user, and additional connections after that) in an app? I couldn't find any information in the docs regarding any sort of global connection error handling.

When this type of connection error occurs, I would like to display a "server overloaded, please try again later." type message to the user, instead of the app just not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [response](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/4RjyYIDqMVQ) I got from a Firebase dev:

> There is no current way to detect this programatically. An error
>   message will be asynchronously thrown in the developer console when
>   the 51st connection is made. I added this to this week's tech
>   discussion to see if we can improve the error handling here.